# How do I import a project within a Go Workspace?

Tags: go, go-modules, go-work

I have a monorepo with multiple modules within it. Some of the modules are libraries, others are entry points that will produce binaries.

Here's my workspace project:
https://github.com/alshdavid/go-workspace-example

I have my "bar" library [here](https://github.com/alshdavid/gotest/blob/main/modules/bar/bar.go) which I would like to make available for import by consumers outside of this mono repo.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/alshdavid/bar"
    // Or maybe: "github.com/alshdavid/gotest/modules/bar"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(bar.Bar)
}
```

Trying to install the package from the workspace git repo results in failure.

```bash
go get github.com/alshdavid/gotest
go get github.com/alshdavid/gotest/modules/bar
go get github.com/alshdavid/bar # worth a shot
```

Is there an argument I should pass to `go get` that instructs to to look for a module in a nested folder or should I instead set up a pipeline that pushes my nested module to its own repository?

Answer (score 3):

You must be working inside a module i.e. `ran: go mod init` in each of your modules in your mono repo.
For example, in your case I am assuming you have module named `bar` and you want to import module `bar` inside another module e.g. `foo`.

A module has a go.mod file. Inside go.mod file of your `foo` module you can add the following:

```
replace github.com/alshdavid/bar => ../bar
```

You can read more about this [here](https://thewebivore.com/using-replace-in-go-mod-to-point-to-your-local-module/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes the `bar` module has a `go.mod` but the repository has a `go.work` denoting that it's a Go workspace. From a module that exists in an external repository (outside the go workspace), I cannot access the library that lives within the aforementioned Go workspace

Answer (score -2):

I just needed the complete path in the `go.mod` file